# Can we find all the labels available in a graph in JanusGraph?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I want to get the list of all the labels available in the graph, but I am unaware of the schema. Is there any way to find out the list of all the labels?

I have tried the following:

```
g.V().Label().values()
g.V().hasLabel().values()
```

but they are not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Gremlin you would do:

```
g.V().label().dedup()
```

but that would require a scan of all vertices in the graph which would be expensive. JanusGraph has schema you can query with the `JanusGraphManagement` class.

```
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
Iterable<VertexLabel> labels = mgmt.getVertexLabels();
```

Comment: How can I create `graph`? I'm using remote connection with code below `GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");` This gives a traversal but I want `JanusGraph` instance.

Comment: you can't get a JanusGraph instance remotely. typically you do not work with Graph instance directly with remotes/Gremlin. if you simply must work with the Graph instance remotely you have to submit a script through the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insights. I just hard-coded the edge types in my Java codes since the types change rarely. I couldn't find any other solution. JanusGraph needs to consider all these requests.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, if all you have is a GraphTraversalSource from a JanusGraph, you can do:

```
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph

val graph: JanusGraph = g.getGraph.asInstanceOf[JanusGraph]
val mgmt: JanusGraphManagement = graph.openManagement()
```

and then from there get your iterable of vertex labels:

```
 val vLabels: Iterable[VertexLabel] = mgmt.getVertexLabels.asScala
```

(The .asScala only works if you have imported [gremlin-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.michaelpollmeier/gremlin-scala_2.13); otherwise you can omit it and you'll get a Java iterator.)